# rviz not showing any data

Tags: ros-melodic, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Melodic and the Velodyne Driver ros-melodic-velodyne. I haven't found a VLP-32C tutorial for the Velodyne Driver although what I see here http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne, says that the VLP-32C is supported. I used [this VLP-16 tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Velodyne%20VLP16) and [this HDL-32E tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E) but changed the input files for the VLP-32C.
The output from rosrun gives an error:

```
$ rosrun velodyne_pointcloud gen_calibration.py 32db.xml
```

converting "32db.xml" to "32db.yaml"
gen_calibration.py: unable to read 32db.xml

From what I found, this is fine because the as of 1.5, the yaml file is already created. This should be why I couldn't find VeloView-VLP-32C.xml.

The output from roslaunch seems fine:

```
 $ roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP-32C_points.launch calibration:=/opt/ros/melodic/share/velodyne_pointcloud/params/VeloView-VLP-32C.yaml

... logging to /home/shimron/.ros/log/51d45dac-9248-11e9-bb1c-c8d9d2836857/roslaunch-LiDAR-5140.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://LiDAR:35601/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud/calibration: /opt/ros/melodic/...
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud/max_range: 130.0
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud/min_range: 0.4
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/cut_angle: -0.01
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/device_ip: 
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/frame_id: velodyne
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/model: 32C
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/pcap: 
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/port: 2368
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/read_fast: False
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/read_once: False
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/repeat_delay: 0.0
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver/rpm: 600.0
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan/resolution: 0.007
 * /velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan/ring: -1

NODES
  /
    velodyne_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5150]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 51d45dac-9248-11e9-bb1c-c8d9d2836857
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5161]
started core service [/rosout]
process[velodyne_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [5168]
process[velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver-3]: started with pid [5169]
process[velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud-4]: started with pid [5170]
process[velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan-5]: started with pid [5172]
^X^C[velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan-5] killing on exit
[velodyne_nodelet_manager_cloud-4] killing on exit
[velodyne_nodelet_manager_driver-3] killing on exit
[velodyne_nodelet_manager-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

When I run `rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne`, I see the GUI but no data from the sensor. I have point cloud and point cloud 2 selected under add->rviz. I can ping the sensor.
My graphics card is GeForce GTX 1070. I tried to implement this [rviz solution](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting) but from `rostopic info /tf`I get:

```
Type: tf2_msgs/TFMessage

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /rostopic_4686_1560947462150 (http://LiDAR:39601/)
```

And from `rosnode info robot_state_publisher` I get

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/robot_state_publisher]
Publications: None

Subscriptions: None

Services: None

cannot contact [/robot_state_publisher]: unknown node
```

I did try to troubleshoot /tf and found that I should test turtle examples but those didn't work. I'm not sure if those outputs would be helpful so let me know if you'd like them.
Thanks in advance for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326263/rviz-not-showing-any-data/) by [rabrn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43084/rabrn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a couple things to check for: First, when you `rostopic echo` your pointcloud, Do you see data there? And what is the frame_id in the header? If you see data there, you can tell rviz to show everything in the frame of your point cloud (probably velodyne), which should work. You can select which frame to display things in from the Global Options -> Fixed Frame field in rviz.

It also appears that you don't have a `/robot_state_publisher` running at all, and you don't have anything publishing tfs. What is the output of `rostopic info /tf_static`? Is anything publishing static tfs? If not, that explains why rviz didn't display anything, because it didn't know how to translate from it's main display frame to velodyne frame.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rabrn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43084/rabrn/) on 2019-06-20**:
When I run `rostopic echo velodyne_points` in a separate terminal from `roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP-32C_points.launch pcap:=$(pwd)/20190604_205742test.pcap -v`, I do see the data. Here is a small sample:

```
21, 75, 62, 252, 151, 127, 0]
is_dense: True
```

The frame_id I get in the header of `rostopic echo /scan` is velodyne. When I run  `rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne` followed by `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 2 0 0 0 odom velodyne 100` to change the frame to velodyne, I don't get any visual data. I also don't see where to change the viewing frame. Global options has fixed frame selected and listed as velodyne but I haven't figured out how to change that. There don't seem to be any other options shown.
The output of `rostopic info /tf_static` is:
Type: tf2_msgs/TFMessage
Publishers: None
Subscribers:
* /rviz_1561005941558178475 (http://LiDAR:33929/)
I've tried to get `/robot_state_publisher` running but haven't gotten that going for pcap files.

**Comment by [rabrn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43084/rabrn/) on 2019-06-20**:
I got it! I had the wrong pcap2 display selected. Once I selected the one under topic->velodyne_points it worked.
Thanks for your help!